# rtrim function doesn't work with ending h letter

Tags: php

```
$file = "refinish.php";
$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
echo $folder; // refinis
```

where is ending `h` ?

I tried with some other ending letters - it's ok.

Comment: what you expected result ?

Comment: @VadivelS, I expected `refinish`, of course. And don't want to remove `.php` if it is at the beginning or in the middle of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rtrim()` does not remove the string you specify in the second argument, but **all characters** in that string. In your case, that includes "h".

What you need here is a simple `str_replace()`:

```
$folder = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
```

**Edit**: if you want to make sure it strips the ".php" part only from the end of the `$file`, you can go with @racetrack's suggestion below and use `preg_replace()` instead:

```
$folder = preg_replace('/\.php$/', '', $file);
```

Comment: what a stupid language. thanks a lot. I don't need to remove `.php` if it is at the beginning, or in the middle of string.

Comment: @bonaca - if you read the docs, it tells you exactly what rtrim does (with examples)..... that's not stupid, it's doing exactly what it says it does.... but there are better functions if you only want to remove a file extension from a filename such as [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker, yes, I believe that docs says like you said, but it should say something different - `trim` means `trim`, doesn't it. Thanks fou your `pathinfo` link, it's usefull for me.

Comment: Then perhaps you should write your own variant of the trim function (mytrim()) that does what you want it to do; but there are many ways of doing what you want (substr()) being the most obvious that can remove remove a fixed number of characters from the end of a string

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks for your idea. I will write not a function, but entire language `myphp` using real meanings. `replace` will be `replace` `trim` will be `trim` and not `trim but... `.

Comment: Well when you do, make sure that its properly documented, so that anybody else using it can understand what your real meanings are for each function name

Answer (score 1):

`rtrim`'s second argument is not the substring to remove but a set of characters—could also be a range. You can use `preg_replace` if you want to make sure only the trailing `.php` is removed. e.g.,

```
preg_replace("/\.php$/", "", "refinish.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = "refinish.php";
$folder = str_replace('.','',rtrim($file, "php"));
echo $folder; // refinis
```

Answer (score 0):

You Try code

```
$filename = "refinish.php";
$extension_pos = strrpos($filename , '.');  
$file = substr($filename, 0, $extension_pos) ;

$folder = str_replace('.','',rtrim( $file , "php"));
echo $folder.substr($filename, $extension_pos);
```

its working fine . its output is **refinis.php**

Answer (score 0):

How rtrim() works

```
$file = "finish.php";
$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
```

is processed working through the characters in $file from the last character backwards as

```
$file = "finish.php";
//                ^
//     Is there a `p` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                       ^
//     Yes there is, so remove the `p` from the `$file` string

$file = "finish.ph";
//               ^
//     Is there a `h` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                        ^
//     Yes there is, so remove the `h` from the `$file` string

$file = "finish.p";
//              ^
//     Is there a `p` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                       ^
//     Yes there is, so remove the `p` from the `$file` string

$file = "finish.";
//             ^
//     Is there a `.` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                      ^
//     Yes there is, so remove the `.` from the `$file` string

$file = "finish";
//            ^
//     Is there a `h` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                        ^
//     Yes there is, so remove the `h` from the `$file` string

$file = "finis";
//           ^
//     Is there a `s` in the list of characters to trim

$folder = rtrim($file, ".php");
//                      ????
//     No there isn't, so terminate the checks and return the current value of `$file`

$file = "finis";
```